# How to change the hostname for the Xcode service on Mac Server

Tags: xcode, server.app

I needed to change the hostname of the server I have setup after I started the Xcode service. My server is currently named as follows...

[image: I have my server configured like the following image.]

Except, to view the Xcode service I still need to enter the old hostname (with hyphens), I have tried rebooting the computer and the service, no luck.

[image]

How do I change the hostname that is displayed in the "Status" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up just being an inconsistency in the UI.

I was trying to give my server the computer name `Server Mac 1` with the hostname `ServerMac1`.

But it seems like the wizard that allows you to type in the hostname field totally ignores what you typed when you click Save and instead takes the computer name field as the hostname. It then replaces spaces with '-'.

I ended up entering the computer name as `ServerMac1` and now the hostname is also `ServerMac1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest in the Terminal. SSH into the server and then at the command line :-

```
sudo scutil --set HostName new_name
```

You will be asked for your password and then the name will be changed.